# `time` benchmarking utility: What does `user`+`sys` = 0 actually mean?

Tags: c++, fortran

One comparison I felt that was missing from the [Why is this C++ program so incredibly fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829246/why-is-this-c-program-so-incredibly-fast?newsletter=1&nlcode=318853|5cec) discussion is Fortran.  I translated [Sven Hager's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1326042/sven-hager) C++ benchmark:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  uint32_t s = 0;
  uint32_t outer = atoi(argv[1]);
  uint32_t inner = atoi(argv[2]);
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < outer; ++i) {
    for (uint32_t j = 0; j < inner; ++j)
      ++s;
    s -= inner;
  }
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

to its Fortran equivalent:

```
PROGRAM Benchmark
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER :: i,j,s
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: outer=1000,inner=1000000
  s = 0
  DO i = 1, outer
    DO j = 1, inner
      s = s + 1
    END DO
    s = s - inner
  END DO
PRINT *, s
END PROGRAM Benchmark
```

and compiled a fully optimized version with `gfortran -g -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -O3 Benchmark.f08`.  I expected to acheive similar performance as Herr Hager:

```
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.002s
```

What I got was a little puzzling:

```
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Digging more deeply, I found this discussion on [What do 'real', 'user' and 'sys' mean in the output of time(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1).  In it they say that `user`+`sys` gives the actual CPU time the process used.  **So, what does a `user`+`sys` of zero actually mean?**

Comment: It meas that the execution time of the process is less than 0.001s (1 ms). In your Fortran version your hardcode the `inner/outter` bounds so the loop can be suppressed and `s` computed at compile time. In the C++ you take user args so the compiler cant make similar optimizations. Its unfair.

Comment: quantdev, I would choose the word _inequitable_ rather than 'unfair,' but that's just me.  Nonetheless, I really appreciate your input.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, "zero" means "less than a millisecond" (or half a millisecond, depending on how it's rounded), since that's the resolution of the times given by `time`.

It's only useful for measuring programs that take considerably longer than a millisecond to run.

The reason that the Fortran version is much faster is probably because the loop bounds are hard-coded constants, so that the entire calculation can be done at compile time, leaving just `PRINT 0` to do at runtime.

Comment: How would one modify the C++ code such that `inner` and `outer` are hard-coded, as I have done?  Also, what would be the proper flags for the compiler in addition to the `-O3` flag?  (I'm not a "C person".)  Thanks.

Comment: @JoelDeWitt: Use constants rather than reading from input, just as the Fortran does. `uint32_t outer = 1000, inner = 1000000;`.